# Ionic CLI 3.8 Update - Cordova is not available

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

### Background

After updating my Ionic CLI on two completely separate Ionic apps (for verification of the error), I have tried compiling, building, running, and emulating these apps both on my iPhone and on the XCode emulator. Here is the warning I received after the update:

```
> twine-app@0.0.1 run /Users/Anthony/dev/twine-app
> ionic cordova run ios --l --consolelogs

✖ cordova platform add ios --save - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
✔ cordova platform save - done!
[WARN] Detected @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova in your package.json.

       As of CLI 3.8, it is no longer needed. You can uninstall it.

[WARN] Multiple network interfaces detected!
```

So, after seeing this warning, I tried running the app both using `livereload` on my iPhone and in the XCode emulator using the following lines of code:

```
ionic cordova run ios --livereload --consolelogs
```

and

```
ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload --consolelogs
```

### Error

After that, I began receiving a warning on the call of every Cordova plugin stating that `cordova is not available`:

Examples include but are not limited to:

```
[00:44:00]  console.warn: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to 
            include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator 
[00:44:00]  console.warn: Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include 
            cordova.js or run in a device/simulator 
[00:44:00]  console.warn: Native: tried calling SpeechRecognition.requestPermission, but Cordova is not available. Make 
            sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

### Approach

Here is everything I've tried to fix these errors and their outcomes:

1. `ionic cordova build ios`: Cordova plugins work on my actual device and everything loaded fine with no error. However, this isn't really a fix since I need livereload to test my apps.
2. `ionic cordova platform rm ios && ionic cordova platform add ios`: Removing and adding the iOS platform is ineffective.
3. `npm install -g ionic@latest cordova@latest --save`: Removing the `ionic` and `cordova` npm packages and installing them back doesn't do anything, either.
4. `npm i`: Removing `node_modules` and installing all modules again doesn't fix this issue.
5. `fetch-plugins`: Installing [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-fetch-plugins), deleting the `plugins` folder in the root project directory, and calling `fetch-plugins` has no effect.

As this issue has come up on both of the Ionic apps I am currently developing, I'm afraid more people will come across this issue upon updating their Ionic CLIs. If anyone has any clue how to go about solving this issue, please comment below or post a solution. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ionic Team released `Ionic CLI 3.8.1` shortly after their `3.8` release, so all I had to do to fix this error is to run the following command:

`ionic cordova emulate --address=localhost -slc ios`

and then I received the option to upgrade my Ionic CLI:

```
? The Ionic CLI (local version) has an update available (3.8.0 => 3.8.1)! Would 
you like to install it? Yes
✔ npm install --save-dev --save-exact ionic@latest - done!

[OK] Updated Ionic CLI to 3.8.1!
```

All my Cordova plugins are working fine now.

Comment: i am getting the same issue, but by running the command, i am unable to fix my issue. Did u do something else here? Please let me know.

Comment: I am getting the following errors:   
  
   
`xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
  { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:iPhone 5s }

 The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.

 Ineligible destinations for the "cSmart" scheme:
  { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args`